# How to insert bulk record in SQLite table from result of a SQL Server query through C# or directly from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, c#-4.0, ssms

I have thousands of records from a SQL Server 2014 stored procedure result set, and I insert them one by one into a SQLite DB table through C# code, which takes around 4-5 minutes. I need to reduce this time.

I am looking for something like:

```
insert into 'sqlite_table' 
    select * 
    from 'sql_server_table'
```

Any answer with C# code or anything direct from SQL Server script can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

On your C# Code. Use `SqlTransaction` to fasten the insertion of records from one table to another.

Comment: but is there any bulk insertion type possibility ??

Answer (score 0):

I Have done same thing in Sql Server to MySql. For that first I stopped the AutoCommit (Set AutoCommit=False). After the query run the commit command. It gave me good performance. You can try the same if it works for you.

Comment: thnx for ur reply deepak, I did the same but could not found any improvement